# to prove this inequality $\sum a^3b+3\ge 2(ab+bc+ca)$

Tags: inequality, substitution, a.m.-g.m.-inequality, buffalo-way

let $a,b,c>0$ and such $a+b+c=3$,show that
$$a^3b+b^3c+c^3a+3\ge 2(ab+bc+ac)$$

This problem is from my question when $n=3$ case,I found not to prove it. 
 [show this inequality with $\sum_{i=1}^{n}a_{i}=n$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3068203/show-this-inequality-with-sum-i-1na-i-n/3082379#3082379)

I have try  use AM-GM since  $$\sum (a^3b+ab)\ge 2\sum a^2b$$

Answer (score 1):

We need to prove that
$$27(a^3b+b^3c+c^3a)+(a+b+c)^4\geq6(ab+ac+bc)(a+b+c)^2.$$

Let $a=\min\{a,b,c\}$, $b=a+u$ and $c=a+v$.

Thus, by AM-GM
$$27(a^3b+b^3c+c^3a)+(a+b+c)^4-6(ab+ac+bc)(a+b+c)^2=45(u^2-uv+v^2)a^2+$$
$$+9(3u^3+5u^2v-4uv^2+3v^3)a+u^4+25u^3v-6u^2v^2-2uv^3+v^4\geq$$
$$\geq25u^3v-8u^2v^2+\frac{1}{2}v^4+2u^2v^2-2uv^3+\frac{1}{2}v^4=$$
$$=\frac{v}{2}\left(25u^3+25u^3+v^3-16u^2v\right)+v^2\left(2u^2+\frac{1}{2}v^2-2uv\right)\geq$$
$$\geq\frac{v}{2}\left(3\sqrt[3]{\left(25u^3\right)^2v^3}-16u^2v\right)+v^2\left(2\sqrt{2u^2\cdot\frac{1}{2}v^2}-2uv\right)=\frac{u^2v^2}{2}\left(3\sqrt[3]{625}-16\right)\geq0.$$
Another proof.

Let $a+b+c=3u$, $ab+ac+bc=3v^2$, $abc=w^3$ and $u^2=tv^2.$

Thus, $t\geq1$ and we need to prove that
$$\sum_{cyc}2a^3b+6u^4\geq12u^2v^2$$ or
$$\sum_{cyc}(a^3b+a^3c)+6u^4-12u^2v^2\geq\sum_{cyc}(a^3c-a^3b)$$ or
$$27u^2v^2-18v^4-3uw^3+6u^4-12u^2v^2\geq(a+b+c)(a-b)(b-c)(c-a)$$ or
$$2u^4+5u^2v^2-6v^4-uw^3\geq u(a-b)(b-c)(c-a)$$ and since $$2u^4+5u^2v^2-6v^4-uw^3\geq0,$$ it's enough to prove that
$$(2u^4+5u^2v^2-6v^4-uw^3)^2\geq u^2(a-b)^2(b-c)^2(c-a)^2$$ or
$$(2u^4+5u^2v^2-6v^4-uw^3)^2\geq27u^2(3u^2v^4-4v^6-4u^3w^3+6uv^2w^3-w^6)$$ or
$$7u^2w^6+(26u^4-43u^2v^2+3v^4)uw^3+u^8+5u^6v^2-20u^4v^4+12u^2v^6+9v^8\geq0.$$
Now, since 
$$u^8+5u^6v^2-20u^4v^4+12u^2v^6+9v^8=v^8(t^4+5t^3-20t^2+12t+9)=$$
$$=v^8\left(\left(\frac{t^2}{4}+2t\right)(2t-3)^2+\frac{1}{4}(7t^2-24t+36)\right)\geq0,$$
it's enough to prove our inequality for $26t^2-43t+3\leq0,$ for which it's enough to prove that
$$(26t^2-43t+3)^2-28(t^4+5t^3-20t^2+12t+9)\leq0$$ or
$$(t-1)^2(9+40t-24t^2)\geq0,$$ which is true because
$$9+40t-24t^2=9+40t+\frac{24}{26}\left(-26t^2\right)\geq9+40t+\frac{24}{26}\left(3-43t\right)>0.$$
Done!

Comment: Is there a method that doesn't use this 'buffalo' approach?

Comment: @user574848 I think, the proof by BW is an easiest here. There is also a proof by the $uvw$'s technique, but it's very ugly.

Comment: You could also try the Lagrange multiplier method.

Answer (score 0):

A numeric approach.

Substitute $c=3-(a+b)$, we need to show that
$$
f(a,b)=a^3 b+2 \left(a^2+a (b-3)+(b-3) b\right)-b^3 (a+b-3)-a (a+b-3)^3+3 \ge 0
$$
on the triangle
$$
T = \{(a,b): 0 \le a \le 3, 0 \le b \le 3\}
$$

Using interval arithmetic libraries like [`IntervalRootFinding.jl`](https://juliaintervals.github.io/IntervalRootFinding.jl/stable/)
one can check **rigorously** that there are there are only 4 roots of $\nabla f$ in $T$.

```
 Root([0.224206, 0.224207] × [0.940989, 0.94099], :unique)
 Root([1.8348, 1.83481] × [0.224206, 0.224207], :unique)  
 Root([0.999999, 1.00001] × [0.999999, 1.00001], :unique) 
 Root([0.940989, 0.94099] × [1.8348, 1.83481], :unique)
```

At these 4 points, $f$ take the following values

```
  [1.22651, 1.22652]      
  [1.22651, 1.22652]      
 [-1.4608e-09, 1.4608e-09]
  [1.22651, 1.22652]
```

So the only possible minimal point is

```
Root([0.999999, 1.00001] × [0.999999, 1.00001], :unique)
```

which we know by analytic method is simply $(1,1)$. And $f(1,1)=0$.

The four root are shown in the picture
[image]

Of course you can still need to check there's no negative points on the boundary. But that's trivial.